# Apache virtual host allow NOT overriding server allow

Tags: apache-2.4, access-control-list

I am running Apache 2.4 and according to the documentation I found on the apache website (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html), under the section "How the sections are merged" it says that the virtual host configurations should override the server configurations.

I have a filesmatch server config regex to prevent public access to important wordpress files using "order deny, allow" logic:

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php|admin-ajax\.php">
   Include conf/global_acl.conf
</FilesMatch>
```

Then under my virtual host I have another filesmatch to allow specific access to certain files to enable a wordpress plugin:

```
<FilesMatch "^(xmlrpc|wp-trackback)\.php$">
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from wordpress.com
   Allow from 123.123.123.123
</FilesMatch>
```

My goal is to have the server config allow process, be inherited by the virtual host, then have the additional allow directives parsed by the virtual host. It does not seem to be working. If I modify the server level by removing the xmlrpc file, the virtual host will work.

*EDIT*

To clear up confusion, my issue is that under the virtual host, I am being denied even though I am using IP 123.123.123.123. I am expecting the whitelist entries from the server config to be inherited by the virtual host. Then having additional whitelisted allows in the virtualhost config. I have a DENY FROM ALL at the top of my server config.

Any ideas what is going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the appropriate AllowOverride directive set?

Comment: Isn't that just for htaccess files to override the configs? the above configs are being done in the main config file.

Answer (score 0):

A change made in 2.4 was the replacement of the syntax **Allow from** by the new **Require all granted** and similar.  See [apache upgrading doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) section *Access control*.

There is a compat module you can use to avoid changes. If you use it, and choose `Order Deny,Allow` then if you have no `Deny` statements, all accesses will be allowed (see [apache compat: Order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order)).

So either use `Order Allow,Deny` or add a `Deny from all`.

Comment: I have the mod_access_compat module loaded though.

Comment: ok. you  probably need a `Deny from all` in your  2nd FilesMatch.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear. See my edit. The issue in particular is that I am not being allowed from 123.123.123.123